# Cancel promises in Promise.map if one is rejected (Bluebird 3)

Tags: bluebird

I use Bluebird 3 with enabled cancellation.  Is cancellation the tool to use in the following use case:

```
var resourcesPromise = Promise.map(resourceIds, function(id) {
    return loadResource(id);
});

resourcesPromise.catch(function() {
    resourcesPromise.cancel();
});`
```

If one of the resources fails to load, resourcesPromise will be rejected, and I want to stop the loading of all other resources.  But as far as I can tell, cancelling resourcesPromise doesn't work, because it is already rejected.

Edit:  I'm currently considering variants of the following:

```
var resourcesPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var intermediatePromise = Promise.map(resourceIds, function(id) {
        return loadResource(id).catch(function(error) {
            intermediatePromise.cancel();
            reject(error);
        });
    }).then(resolve, reject);
});
```

(I may have found a legitimate use for the ".then(resolve, reject)" anti-pattern!)

Any ideas why Promise.map doesn't work like that?

Comment: did you ever figure out an answer to do it in parallel, but to cancel if one fails?

Answer (score 0):

With map you are parallelizing the resource loading, maybe is better to use Promise.each to laoad resources in sequence. In such case you don't need to cancel the promise to stop loading the remaining resources when one fails.

```
var resourcesPromise = Promise.map(resourceIds, function(id) {
    return loadResource(id);
});

resourcesPromise.catch(function() {
    resourcesPromise.cancel();
});`
```

Another option would be to pass to the map function an option object like in which you can specify the concurrency limit.

```
Promise.resolve(resourceIds).
map(function(id) {
  return loadResource(id);
}, {concurrency: n}).
catch(function(e) {
  //do some error handling
});
```

Comment: I am deliberately parallelizing the resouce loading to make it faster.  Thank you for the answer, but this doesn't work for me.